# Jquery and AngularJS routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I don't have long experience with web programming. Now I have issue with Angular route and jquery events.
In main page I show navbar when I scroll with this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).scroll(function() {
        "use strict";
        if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#slider').height())
        {
           $('#header').addClass('header_fixed animated fadeInDown');
           $('.logo').addClass('logo_fix');
           $('.nav-collapse').addClass('nav-collapse_margin_top');
           $('#header_cotact_icon').hide();
           $('#header_navigation').addClass('header_navigation_fixed');
           $('.logo').addClass('widd');
           $('#wrap').addClass('body-margin-top-20');
        }
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() < $('#header').height())
            {
                $('#header').removeClass('header_fixed animatedfadeInDown');
                $('.logo').removeClass('logo_fix');
                $('#header_cotact_icon').show();
                $('#header_navigation').removeClass('header_navigation_fixed');
                $('.logo img').removeClass('widd');
                $('#wrap').removeClass('body-margin-top-20');
            }                        


    });

</script>
```

and also I implement simple route with anuglar. When I load other site this navbar is visible becouse 'if' instruction is true.
What can I do if I don't want to use above script on loaded page?
I thought about angular controllers but I don't have an idea, how to take scroll positon without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could help you. I shrink my navbar, if the user scrolls down (one page site). I use this (i copied it from somewhere but didn't found it):

index.html:

```
 <div class="" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
       <span scroll-position="scrollPos"></span>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-class="{'navbar-shrink': scrollPos > 1}">
         <div class="container">
```

NavbarCtrl:

```
angular.module('yourappname')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.scrollPos = 0;
  });
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('yourappname')
  .directive('scrollPosition', function ($window) {
    return {
      scope: {
        scrollPos: "=scrollPosition"
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var windowElement = angular.element($window);
        var handler = function () {
          scope.scrollPos = windowElement.scrollTop();
        }
        windowElement.on('scroll', scope.$apply.bind(scope, handler));
        handler();
      }
    };
  });
```

This is how you can handle the scrollposition within a directive. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take scroll value in `Angular.js` inside a controller

```
app.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope,$window){
    angular.element($window).bind('scroll',function(){
        console.log($window.scrollY);
        //Rest of your logic
    });
});
```

`$window` is angular wrapper around browser window object. you can use `$window.scrollX` and `$window.scrollY` to do some work.